# How to show three complex numbers are collinear?

Tags: geometry

I have recently stumbled upon a geometry problem.

> > Let be a ABC triangle inscribed in a semicircle with center O and diameter BC. Two tangent lines to the semicircle at A and B intersect at D. Prove that DC goes through the midpoint of the altitude AH of triangle ABC.
>
> I want to solve it via complex numbers, and I have found the values of $D$, $C$, and $H$, yet I don't know how to demonstrate that they are collinear.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to just write out Cartesian coordinates.

WLOG the circle is unit circle, $B=(-1,0)$, $C=(1,0)$, $A=(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ where $\theta\in (0,\pi)$

Then $H=(\cos\theta, 0)$ and $AH$ has equation $x=\cos \theta$

The tangent line through $B$ is $x=-1$

The tangent line through $A$ is $(y-\sin\theta)=-\cot\theta(x-\cos\theta)$

Solve the equation to find their intersection $x=-1$, $y=(1+\cos\theta)\cot\theta+\sin\theta=\frac{\cos\theta+\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta}{\sin\theta}=\frac{1+\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}$

$D=(-1,\frac{1+\cos\theta}{\sin\theta})$

Therefore the equation of $CD$ is $y=\frac{1+\cos\theta}{-2\sin\theta}(x-1)$

Then find the intersection with $AH$, plug in $x=\cos\theta$, we get $y=\frac{(1+\cos\theta)(\cos\theta-1)}{-2\sin\theta}=\frac{-\sin^2\theta}{-2\sin\theta}$=$\frac{\sin\theta}{2}$. Therefore it is the midpoint of $AH$.

Comment: Oh thanks! However, how did you choose the coordinates for A?

Comment: Coordinates on a circle is $(\cos\theta, \sin\theta)$ by the unit circle definition of trig. functions. If we choose $B$ and $C$ to be those coordinates then we can pick $A$ on the upper semicircle.